# Python APScheduler keyerror

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, apscheduler

I have created a .exe file for a .py file with cx_Freeze and pyinstaller, and when im running that file, cmd is generating error:

```
File "site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 893, in _create_plugin_instance
KeyError: 'interval'
```

i have defined a apscheduler job as:

```
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=120)
```

I dont know how to handle this error, when im running my .py file there is no error generated.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cx_Freeze and PyInstaller both omit metadata vital to APScheduler from the packed .exe file. For this reason, setuptools entry points do not work. The workaround:

```
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

@sched.scheduled_job(IntervalTrigger(seconds=120))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, can i ask how 'IntervalTrigger' works when 'Trigger' is not working ? and whats the effect of setuptools entry point on APScheduler ? It would be kind of you if answer, Thanks

Comment: What "Trigger" are you talking about? Regarding your second question, when you give `add_job()` a string in place of a trigger instance, it looks up the corresponding trigger class using the setuptools entry point by that name. The full list of registered entry point names are located in APScheduler's `setup.py` file.